# Macro preprocessor directive

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have idea about macro preprocessor directive.In below question how replacement in source code is done by compiler that it is giving output as 
"y is 392"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define CUBE(x) (x*x*x)
void main(void)
{
     int x;
     int y;
     x = 5;
     y = CUBE(++x);
     printf("y is %d\n", y);
}
```

output:y is 392.

Comment: It's UB — undefined behaviour — because you end up with `y = (++x*++x*++x);` and you can't do multiple increments on a single variable between two sequence points (within a single assignment).  Also, note too that the macro miscomputes the cube if used with `y = CUBE(x + 3);`.  Use parentheses around arguments and around the expression — `#define CUBE(x) ((x)*(x)*(x))`.

Comment: It's an undefined operation. The macro expands to `(++x*++x*++x)`.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour of your code is *undefined*.

`CUBE(++x)` expands to `(++x * ++x * ++x)`: there are no sequencing points in that expression and it simultaneously reads and writes to `x`.

This epitomises why macros that do arithmetic are computationally lethal.

Answer (score 0):

The preprocessor is replacing that with

```
y = (++x*++x*++x);
```

Which is undefined behaviour.